# Using multiple languages on one HTML page

Tags: html, multilingual, html-encode

My simple question is, how can I use multiple languages in one HTML page?

Something like

```
<div>
  <p>This text is in English</p>
</div>

<div>
 <p>This text in Japanese</p>
</div>

<div>
 <p>This text in French</p>
</div>
```

It's for a language selector. The page is pure HTML.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything?  In the example you're showing, did you try just copying the text they have?  As long as you have the right character encoding, you can use whatever text characters you want.  HTML isn't actually going to _translate_ anything for you, you just put the text on the page where you want it.

Comment: Perhaps utilize css or give each div a property. e.g. text direction, if a langage is written right to left. Or for example, the text-transform property takes into account language-specific case mapping rules.

Answer (score 1):

One tricky way to do it, is to set your CSS with, for example:

```css
[lang=en-GB] [lang=fr-FR],
[lang=en-GB] [lang=ja-JP],
[lang=fr-FR] [lang=en-GB],
[lang=fr-FR] [lang=ja-JP],
[lang=ja-JP] [lang=en-GB],
[lang=ja-JP] [lang=fr-FR]
{
    display: none !important;
}
```

And then mark your HTML with the `lang` attribute, such as:

```html
<div lang="en-GB">
  <p>This text is in English</p>
</div>

<div lang="ja-JP">
 <p>This text in Japanese</p>
</div>

<div lang="fr-FR">
 <p>This text in French</p>
</div>
```

You can have a simple javascript that detects the language selected and change the `HTML` root document `:root`.

Using jQuery, it would be like this:

```js
    $(document).on('change', 'select[name="lang"]', function(e)
    {
        $(':root').attr('lang', $(this).val() );
    });
```

And automatically, the correct localised version only would be displayed and the other would not be visible.

Comment: Took me a bit to understand the CSS using descendant selectors - if I may summarize: if the descendant `lang` attribute (the `div` in this example) does not match the ancestor `lang` attribute (the document root presumably) then the descendant element is not displayed; otherwise it matches and is displayed.

Comment: @Computable yes you are correct

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is possible. You can have the other language text in Unicode. Check out an example I created for you here:

Code:

Welcome

नमस्कार

வணக்கம்

Answer (score 0):

Just use UTF-8 for your page encoding and it will all work.  Browsers do this naturally; Unicode (of which UTF-8 is a representation) was invented for this.

Answer (score 0):

The same was as you use one language. You just have the limitation that an HTML document has one character encoding, so you cannot use, for example, ISO-8859-1 encoding for French text and some JIS encoding for Japanese text, as you could if you wrote two separate pages.

The conclusion is that you should normally use UTF-8 if possible, and use workarounds like character references if not.

You can, and should, use the `lang` attribute to indicate the language of each part. But this is not necessary for basic functionality, and it’s really just good authoring habit more than anything else for now.

Answer (score 0):

My solution based on the answer from Jacques:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html id="html-tag" lang="en">
  <script>
    //Script for multilingual support, note that detects the language from the browser and sets the html page to that one
    const $htmlTag = document.querySelector("#html-tag")
    switch(navigator.language.substring(0,2)) {
      case "es":
        $htmlTag.lang = "es"
        $htmlTag.classList.add("spanishLang")
        break
      default:
        $htmlTag.classList.add("englishLang")
        break
    }
  </script>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <style type="text/css">

      body [lang=en], 
      body [lang=es] {
        display: none;
      }

      .spanishLang [lang=es] {
        display: inline;
      }

      .englishLang [lang=en] {
        display: inline;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
<body>
    <div>
      <span lang="en">Settings</span>
      <span lang="es">Configuraciones</span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```